# facing problem with citing references styles (ref. serial numbring, curly brackest instead of square bracket) in Latex bibliography in IEEE format

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I want citation in IEEE format for my thesis, I am using below code.

***`main.bib`*** file

```
@article{cummings ,
author = {Arthur B Cummings and David Eftekhary and Frank G House},
title = {The accurate determination of college students’
coefficients of friction},
journal = {Journal of Sketchy Physics},
volume = {13},
year = {2003},
number = {2},
pages = {46--129}
}

@article{Dimitrios ,
author = {Dimitrios Ververidis and Constantine Kotropoulos},
title = {Emotional speech recognition: Resources, features, and methods’},
journal = {Speech Communication},
volume = {48},
year = {2006},
%number = {2},
pages = {Speech Communication}
}


@article{Bjorn ,
author = {Bjorn Schuller and Bogdan Vlasenko and Florian Eyben and Gerhard Rigoll and Andreas Wendemuth},
title = {Acoustic Emotion Recognition: A Benchmark Comparison of Performances'},
journal = { Cognitive Systems, IESK},
%volume = {13},
year = {2009},
%number = {2},
%pages = {46--129}
}
```

***`Thesis_main.tex`*** file

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{main}
```

end

Note:

my bibliography is created in `main.bib` file and my main document function is called in `Thesis_main.tex` file, code is shared accordingly, although `IEEEtran` style coding files are copy paste for formating.

Problems I am currently facing:

1. Numeric citation not cited
2. In my text file citation are looks like : (In this research (5, ) a summarized comparison among three classifiers)

Note: I want my citation to be cited in square brackets and no extra "," should be appear moreover references should be cite by a serial number.

Answer (score -1):

I am using IEEEtran with `\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}`. I get it working.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Could you please elaborate more your answer, perhaps providing a full minimal working example?